# jQuery UI leaving trash elements behind after .hide('blind').remove()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've several `div` elements that at some point the user can hide.

When this happens, a `jQuery('div').hide('blind').remove();` is triggered and hence the elements are first hidden from the viewport and then removed from the **DOM**. When the elements are deleted from the **DOM jQuery-UI** is leaving som trash containers behind (one trash-div for each div hidden and removed):

```
<div class="ui-effects-wrapper" style="font-size: 100%; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; border: medium none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; width: 1032px; height: 0px; float: none; overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

Right now I'm removing them with `jQuery('divs-wrapper-selector').find('.ui-effects-wrapper').remove();` but I want to know why is **jQuery-UI** doing this and if this has side-effects.

Comment: What version of jQuery/jQueryUI are you using?

Comment: jQuery v1.8.3, jQuery-UI v1.9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.hide()` call has not finished in time for your `.remove()` call. You need to supply a callback to the `.hide()` method, like so:

```
$('target-elem').hide('blind', function () {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

For more information, please see http://api.jqueryui.com/hide/

Comment: In callback, I recommend using `$(this).remove();` instead of `$('target-elem').remove();`

Comment: @Dom: Indeed, the proposed solution doesn't worked (the trash elements still were there) but with $(this).remove() it worked like a charm.

Comment: @tbjers: Can you update your answer with Dom's proposal? Thanks.